# Changing position of arrow on AccordionButton

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, accordion

My mission is simple: I want to move the little arrow on a Silverlight Accordion control to be at the top instead of centered. This is proving to be more complex than I expected. (I am still new to XAML and don't have Expression Blend).

So far I have deduced that I need to modify the Style of the AccordionButton. I have already successfully added a Style for the AccordionItem itself and all is working fine, but when I try to modify the button itself nothing happens.

```
<Style TargetType="toolkit:AccordionButton" x:Key="MyAccordionButtonStyle">
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"></Setter>
</Style>
```

Do I need to redo the entire style for the AccordionButton for this to work? I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7033922/1714556) which seems to be what I need to do, but I cannot figure out where to "copy the template" from or where to put it once I have found it. I have tried to find the source template on CodePlex but had no luck. I did find [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/2dd715fc-02a6-41c8-835c-d63db5420160/changing-silverlight-accordion-control-arrow-image) where the first answer seems to have what I am looking for, but where do I need to put that for it to work? I am not sure how to "hook it up" or if I am even going about this the right way, it seems very overly complicated for something so simple.

Comment: Yes, this will replace your current Style, templates can be found even if you don't have Blend [e.g. Github](https://github.com/samueldjack/SilverlightToolkit/blob/master/Controls.Layout.Toolkit/Accordion/AccordionButton.xaml)

Answer (score 0):

First, if you don't have it already, create a folder off the root named "Themes"

Add a new file to that folder, "Generic.xaml" and mark the Build Action to "Resource"

Generic.xaml contents:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk"
   xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit"
   xmlns:system="http://clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
   >

   <Style TargetType="toolkit:AccordionButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource MyAccordionButtonStyle}"/>
</ResourceDictionary>
```